# SQL - How can I do sum of transactions for certain services (that have different pricing) for each month of the year?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlyog

So I had this:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(trans_date) AS Month_Booking, 
    count(transact_no) AS NumTransactions, 
    (price * count(transact_no)) AS TotalRevenue
FROM transaction t
JOIN service s ON t.service_no = s.service_no
WHERE YEAR(trans_date) = 2017
GROUP BY MONTH(trans_date)
ORDER BY MONTH(trans_date) asc;
```

Which returned this result, which is wrong because it doesn't change the price of each service depending on the transaction so the total revenue is wrong here.
[Result of Query Above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56cGx.png)

Then I tried this, which is partly complete since it gives me the revenue of one month - which is correct however since it adding different services depending on each transaction.

```
SELECT 
    sum(TotalRevenue) AS March_Revenue
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        s.service_no, 
        description, 
        count(transact_no) AS NumTransactions, 
        (price * count(transact_no)) AS TotalRevenue, 
        trans_date
FROM service s
JOIN transaction t ON t.service_no = s.service_no
WHERE MONTH(trans_date) = 3 
AND YEAR(trans_date) = 2017
GROUP BY service_no
ORDER BY service_no asc) March;
```

[Result of Query Above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6g1V.png)

What I would like, is to have a query that can somehow obtain total revenue for each month, without having to do it individually like this.

Any particular way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mysql or SQL-server? Cannot be both. Can you please post some sample data, or at least what you expect the final result to look like?

Comment: Not sure how the first example runs as you aren't including the "Price" field in and aggregate function or a group by. Can you just confirm if this is correct?

Comment: @Eli MySQL not sql server. Sorry. Final result, I'd like month: 1,2,3,4 etc. and total revenue: (sum of price of each service from each transaction, per month)

Comment: @chillysapien price is a column. The service table has service_no, description, price

Comment: @mongiie I removed the SQL-Server tag, as per your comment. As for the total revenue, you're not being clear enough. Can you post a few rows of (dummy) data on http://rextester.com or sql fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be missing something, but I think its just

```
SELECT MONTH(trans_date) AS Month_Booking, 
    count(transact_no) AS NumTransactions, 
    sum(price) AS TotalRevenue
FROM transaction t
JOIN service s
ON t.service_no = s.service_no
WHERE YEAR(trans_date) = 2017
GROUP BY MONTH(trans_date)
ORDER BY MONTH(trans_date) asc;
```

Comment: I think price is coming from the service table and is not historized.

Comment: OP might want to clarify, but I can't see anything that implies price changes over time. Their first query was just picking an arbitrary price and multiplying by count for the month. Other flavours of SQL Server would not let this compile, as price is not included in group by, but I am guessing MySql lets it through?

Comment: Services are things like Limo, pool etc etc. Each has a concrete price, set in the service table. Sorry for my ambiguity :(

Comment: This should work then - after joining service to transaction, each transaction has a price, just sum them up and group by month

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless you have the historical price somewhere. If there is a price TRANSACTION_PRICE in the TRANSACTION table is is quite easy:

```
SUM(transaction_price)
```

If there is not you are lost. The data does not exist anymore in the database unless you have some secret auditing tables from which you can work out the historical price.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this work? Assuming service_no and price are 1:1

```
SELECT Month_Booking,
       SUM(cnt_service_no * price) AS Total_Revenue
  FROM (SELECT MONTH(trans_date) AS Month_Booking,
               COUNT(s.service_no) AS cnt_service,
               s.price
          FROM transaction t
         INNER
          JOIN service s
            ON t.service_no = s.service_no
         GROUP
            BY MONTH(trans_date),
               s.service_no,
               s.price
        )
 GROUP 
    BY Month_Booking;
```